# Consulta se ejecuta dos veces

Tags: php, ajax

la siguiente funcion ajax envia los parametros correctamente:

```
    function concatenaredicion(idarchivoaeditar) {
    var contenidoagregar = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();
    data = {
        "texto":contenidoagregar,
        "idinforme":idarchivoaeditar
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        url: 'php/editainforme.php',
        success: function name(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    })
}
```

El problema es que archivo `.php` ejecuta la consulta pero concatena dos veces el mismo valor

```
<?php
    require_once('../conexion.php');
    $texto = $_POST['texto'];
    $informe = $_POST['idinforme'];
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE archivos_informes SET contenido = CONCAT(contenido,?)
        WHERE idArchivo = ? ");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $texto,$informe);
    if (isset($_POST["texto"]) && !empty($_POST["texto"])) {
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            echo "Falló la ejecución";
        }else{
            echo "Informe actualizado";
        }
    }else{  
        echo "Agruegue un contenido";
    }
?>
```

el problema en si es el siguiente:
Si en mi variable `$texto` tiene un valor de `<p>1</p>` en mi base de datos se concatena dos veces de la siguiente manera : `<p>1</p><p>1</p>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema esta aqui:

```
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
```

Estas ejecutando dos veces `$stmt`.  Solo necesitas ejecutar una vez asi:

```
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
```

Comment: muchas gracias, efectivamente